# Rails 4: CSV to hash passed as hidden field

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I have a CSV import method that renders a confirmation / preview page of the data about to be imported, and I want to pass the data from the preview to the actual import method.

In the preview, the CSV has already been turned into a hash of rows and I want to pass that hash to the import method.  I've tried simply doing:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "my_hash", @final %>
```

where `@final` is the hash of data, but it passes the hash as a string and in the params, the data looks like json.

```
 "wi_hash"=>"{
  \"name_fail\"=>[{\"scale_id\"=>\"509\",
     \"name\"=>\"John Doe\",
     \"date\"=>\"<no data>\",
     \"current_weight\"=>\"999\",
     \"bmi\"=>\"999\",
     \"body_fat\"=>\"999\",
     \"visceral_fat\"=>\"999\",
     \"tbw\"=>\"999\",
     \"muscle_mass\"=>\"999\",
     \"basal_metabolic_rate\"=>\"999\"
     ....
  }
```

**How else can I pass `@final` so that it maintains its hash format?**

Comment: What do you mean by "so that it maintains its hash format"? Please edit your question to include an example of what you want the rendered HTML to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful helper in another question:

```
def hash_to_hidden_fields(hash)
  query_string = Rack::Utils.build_nested_query(hash)
  pairs        = query_string.split(Rack::Utils::DEFAULT_SEP)

  tags = pairs.map do |pair|
    key, value = pair.split('=', 2).map { |str| Rack::Utils.unescape(str) }
    hidden_field_tag(key, value)
  end

  tags.join("\n").html_safe
end
```

It allows you to pass the haas as an argument.